# Array to string conversion In Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm getting an " array to string conversion " error in codeigniter ` 
    there is the function

==> Modele

```
public function getCodeActivationWebsite($EmailCode) {

        $this->db->select('advancedActivationWebsiteCode')->from($this->table)->where('advancedActivationEmailCode' , $EmailCode);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();            
    }
```

==> controllers

```
function downloadfile($codeActivation = '') {
        // Read the file's contents
        $name = $this->advanced->getCodeActivationWebsite($codeActivation).'.html';
        $data = file_get_contents(PATH_UPLOADS_ACTIVATION_WEBSITE . $name); // La path n'est pas valide 
        //getCode
        //ActivationWebsite($EmailCode)
        if (force_download($name, $data)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which method is throwing the error?

Comment: I see only two lines that can convert to string, that's the assignment of `$name` and `$data`, but I don't know anything about CodeIgniter, so I don't know what it's supposed to return.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your model function `getCodeActivationWebsite` the data is returned as an object.  Assuming your works query properly this object will contain the string that you want to access.

In your code the object is stored in the `$name` variable, so when you do this: `file_get_contents(PATH_UPLOADS_ACTIVATION_WEBSITE . $name);` you get an error.

Instead you have to identify the string in your object.  For example it might be `$name[0]->name`.  The best way to identify where the string is located is to `print_r` your object and locate the data.

Read more about how to access data from an object here: **[PHP access data of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905223/php-access-data-of-an-object)** or **[PHP: Getting data out of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392704/php-getting-data-out-of-an-object)**