# Getting element from Moodle object

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to get the id value from the following object, but having some trouble. Any thoughts?

```
Array ( [217] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 217 [userid] => 2) )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP access data of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905223/php-access-data-of-an-object)

Comment: Similar question, but does not answer mine. The objects name is $findHomeGrown, so $findHomeGrown[217]->id does not work because the following error is thrown: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Please show us the entire code then, also how you access it and which error you get

Comment: This object is the result of a multiple records query. The simple solution is to do another query based on one record.